# DeclarationError: Identifier already declared

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, import, access

I'm getting the below compile error message:

```
DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. --> contracts/coffeeBase/SupplyChain.sol:9:1: | 9 | import "../coffeeAccessControl/ConsumerRole.sol"; | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Note: The previous declaration is here: --> contracts/coffeeAccessControl/DistributorRole.sol:7:1: | 7 | contract ConsumerRole { | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

For the below imports:

```
import "../coffeeCore/Ownable.sol";
import "../coffeeAccessControl/FarmerRole.sol";
import "../coffeeAccessControl/DistributorRole.sol";
import "../coffeeAccessControl/RetailerRole.sol";
import "../coffeeAccessControl/ConsumerRole.sol";
```

Note, each of these imports from `coffeeAccessControl` import for from a library called `Roles.sol`

Is the compilation error due to this collision? I haven't been able to find any documentation on import collisions etc

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and a superficial look at what you're doing, it is because `Roles.sol` is imported more than once. It would be tempting to hand-wave and just advise you to linearized the inheritance graph so it gets imported exactly once.

In practice, you'll find that very challenging since the dependency is there four times and you need the four versions to compile independently. This ought to set your spidey-senses tingling about the approach itself.

You have a lot of redundant code and a lot of very similar code (I surmise the four role contracts are very similar themselves and, of course, the inherited Roles.sol is identical). This would make for a large contract before anything useful is even defined - just the access control.

I might suggest you try to eliminate the four Role implementations and use a more abstract approach - one module that does it all and an app that defines the roles it needs:

```
bytes32 constant public ADMIN_ROLE = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Admin Role"));
bytes32 constant public TRUSTEE_ROLE = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Trustee Role"));
bytes32 constant public DELEGATE_ROLE = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Delegate Role"));
```

You would modify the functions and modifiers to accept role inputs

For example, the OpenZeppelin Access.sol (and the old Roles.sol, IIRC) implementation gives it to you with:

```
modifier onlyRole(bytes32 role) {
  ...
```

Your app-level contract would stop using modifiers like `onlyAdmin` and start using modifiers like `onlyRole(ADMIN_ROLE)`. You would implement functions in your higher-level contract that uses access-control like this:

```
function grantRole(address user, bytes32 role) external onlyRole(ADMIN_ROLE) {
  // call it
```

You can validate the `role` if you want, and emit events. The main point is this will be more compact and less repetitive than separate functions for every role, like this:

```
function grantAdmin(address user) ...
function grantTrustee(address user) ... 
function grantDelegate(address user) ...
```

If you tackle it that way, it's going to be more compact and you will side-step your inheritance graph challenge. Don't create a whole module where a variable will suffice.

Hope it helps.

Comment: tremendous feedback that points me in the right direction - thank you Rob

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer ;-)